# console.log and arithmatic operations does not work inside (addEventListener) javascript

Tags: javascript

i try to create typing test web application //error  ///
this code i copied from github https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/JS-Speed-Typing-Game
i try to add timer when user press a key..

```
var err=0;
let sttime =0;
console.log(sttime);

quoteInputElement.addEventListener('input', () => {

  err ++; /////does not work
  console.log(sttime);    ///does not work

  console.log('jbjabj');
  const arrayQuote = quoteDisplayElement.querySelectorAll('span');
  const arrayValue = quoteInputElement.value.split('');
  let correct = true;
  arrayQuote.forEach((characterSpan, index) => {
    const character = arrayValue[index];
    
    if (character == null) {
      characterSpan.classList.remove('correct');
      characterSpan.classList.remove('incorrect');
      correct = false
    } else if (character === characterSpan.innerText) {
      characterSpan.classList.add('correct');
      characterSpan.classList.remove('incorrect');
    } else {
      characterSpan.classList.remove('correct');
      characterSpan.classList.add('incorrect');
      correct = false;
    }
  })
  
})

console.log(sttime);
if(sttime == 1){
  startTimer();
}
```

Comment: When you use `addEventListener` the code will be executed *later*. In this case, when there is input. However, you try to attach the handler and immediately try to check wht it did before any input was there. If you want some code to be executed *on input*, then it needs to be *in the event handler* for input.